# Как работает вычисление выражения x < y < z в C++?

Tags: c++, if, сравнение, логические-выражения

Подскажите где ошибка и почему я не прав(

```
    # include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main ()
    {

    int x, y, z;

    cout << "Imput x " << endl; cin >> x; 
    cout << "Imput y " << endl; cin >> y; 
    cout << "Imput z " << endl; cin >> z; 

    if ( y < x < z || z < x < y)
    {cout<<"The middle number is "<<x<<endl;}

    else if ( x < y < z || z < y < x)
    {cout<<"The middle number is "<<y<<endl;}

    else if ( x < z < y || y < z < x)
    {cout<<"The middle number is "<<z<<endl;}

    else if ( x == y && y == z)
    {cout<<"All the numbers are same"<<endl;}
    }
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку** и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Тут и так все просто и ясно, не преувеличивайте.

Comment: Посмотрел историю ваших вопросов. Вам стоит внимательнее относится к формулированию проблем. Название вопроса должно отражать суть, чтобы быть полезным будущим посетителям сайта. ruSO это база знаний, а не пункт индивидуальной помощи.

Comment: Хорошо, как скажите

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что выражения вида

```
y < x < z
```

компилятор воспринимает как

```
(y < x) < z
```

т.е. сначала вычисляется `y < x`, преобразуется в зависимости от его истинности в 0 или 1, и сравнивается с `z`.

Вам следует писать

```
(y < x) && (x < z)
```

Comment: А так только в плюсах или везде ?

Comment: **Везде** - слишком широкое понятие. Я не могу знать все языки...

Comment: @AntonioParroni В `Python` не так, там двойные сравнения работают "интуитивным" образом )